# To create a new directory and a file within it using Java

Tags: java, file, directory

I am trying to create a new directory and a file within this directory. Can any one tell me where am I going wrong?

I am using a Windows system and I want the directory to be present in the folder my `.java` file is present.

```
import java.io.*;
class  PS_Task1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("Library\\test.txt");
            file.mkdir();
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ecception");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is basic of Java. You could get this if you read the documents on basic Java in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileOps.html

Comment: @Rock123  just started on java.felt like asking here and asked.you could point me to a better resource.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Basically, what's happening is, you are creating a directory called `Library\test.txt`, then trying to create a new file called the same thing, this obviously isn't going to work.

So, instead of...

```
File file = new File("Library\\test.txt");
file.mkdir();
file.createNewFile();
```

Try...

```
File file = new File("Library\\test.txt");
file.getParentFile().mkdir();
file.createNewFile();
```

**Additional**

`mkdir` will not actually throw any kind of exception if it fails, which is rather annoying, so instead, I would do something more like...

```
File file = new File("Library\\test.txt");
if (file.getParentFile().mkdir()) {
    file.createNewFile();
} else {
    throw new IOException("Failed to create directory " + file.getParent());
}
```

Just so I knew what the actual problem was...

**Additional**

The creation of the directory (in this context) will be at the location you ran the program from...

For example, you run the program from `C:\MyAwesomJavaProjects\FileTest`, the `Library` directory will be created in this directory (ie `C:\MyAwesomJavaProjects\FileTest\Library`).  Getting it created in the same location as your `.java` file is generally not a good idea, as your application may actually be bundled into a Jar later on.

Comment: this code working in windows but not working in linux .

Comment: The basic principle shod work, assuming you have write permissions to create the directory/file, I use this same technique on MacOS and Unix systems and it works fine

Answer (score 4):

Do this in order to create a new directory inside your project, create a file and then write on it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //System.getProperty returns absolute path
    File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/folder/file.txt");
    if(!f.getParentFile().exists()){
        f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    }
    //Remove if clause if you want to overwrite file
    if(!f.exists()){
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        //dir will change directory and specifies file name for writer
        File dir = new File(f.getParentFile(), f.getName());
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(dir);
        writer.print("writing anything...");
        writer.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

}
```